# Handling custom Roles based users in database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am working on an application in which I am having 5-6 roles. Yes, It's a common thing but I am facing a issue. I am handling the data and tables of my own.

I have checked other posts but most of them is related to Membership.
Well,  to handle this I have created a table that holds columns

**TblUsers**

1. UserId
2. Name
3. Email
4. Roles-- In this column I am storing roles like `Teacher`, `Student` etc

But now I have come across the situation where a user can have 
multiple roles. Suppose a user is a teacher  and a student and also some more.

So, my question is that how should I manage my database so that It should work efficiently and a sensible database handling should reflect and in future also it should work well regarding fetching the roles and checking against the "Roles" and allowing the permissions.

One solution I thought is to keep the roles in different table

**tblRoles**

```
Role_Id      Role
1            Client
2            Teacher
3            Student
4            Superitendent
5            Principal
```

and then keeping the roles in the users table as follows

**tblUsers**

```
User_Id      Name    Email      Roles
1            Pin     hh           1
2            Sin     mm           1,2
3            ll      ii           3,2
4            uu      hv           3
```

or

```
User_Id      Name    Email      Roles
1            Pin     hh         Teacher
2            Sin     mm         Client, Teacher.
```

But doing this will make the things complex in coding?

How will I join and get the roles if I use the above technique
Suppose user who has Id 2 has logged in and to get the roles of user I have to do like this?

```
var Roles=get Roles from tblUsers where user_id= 2
```

then

```
Roles.split(',');
```

then checking the count and getting the roles like this

```
var User_Role = get Role from tblRoles where Role='Roles[0]' ;
```

and If I have more than one values in Roles Array then I have to call Database again and again?

Please help me regarding this. Your suggestions would be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your tables like this:
tblUsers:

```
User_Id      Name    Email
1            Pin     hh
2            Sin     mm
3            ll      ii
4            uu      hv
```

tblRoles:

```
Role_Id      Role
1            Client
2            Teacher
3            Student
4            Superitendent
5            Principal
```

tblUserRoles:

```
User_Id      Role_Id
1            1
1            2
1            5
3            4
3            2
```

For using this table you can simply using sql queries like this:

```
WITH Roles_CTE(User_Id, Role) AS(
SELECT User_Id.tblUserRoles, Role.tblRoles FORM tblUserRoles INNER JOIN tblRoles
ON tblUserRoles.Role_Id = tblRoles.Role_Id)

SELECT User_Id.tblUsers, Name.tblUsers, Role.Roles_CTE FROM
Roles_CTE INNER JOIN tblUsers ON tblUsers.User_Id = Roles_CTE.User_Id
```

And for using this query in c# you should use ADO.NET components.
For sql-server users like you there is `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Well the classic solution in text book is to make three table:

1. User table with at least one userid column.
2. Role table with at least one roleid column.
3. A relation table links user table and role table with at least one userid column and one roleid column.

For each role a user has, there should be a row in relation table which userid is the user's id and roleid is corresponding role's id. This solution is most flexible and extensible, and when you need query some information, if you can use the SQL's "join table" trick proficiently, it will never be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table as UserRoleMapping with columns

MappingID, User_Id, Role_Id

The table will have multiple rows against a user according to the number of roles assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

the typical way to do this is with a different table that contains the roles.
like.... err user_roles(user_id, roles) where user_id is a foreign key.

```
USER_ID    ROLES
1          1
1          2
2          2
```

so that this table is many to one relationship with your users table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Roles` column and add `UserRole` table. This is best way.

The key to resolve m:n relationships is to separate the two entities and create two one-to-many (1:n) relationships between them with a third intersect entity.

[image]

If you use Entity Framework, all query will be simple. 
For example:

```
db.Users.Find(2).Roles.ToList(); //Get all roles of User(2)
db.Roles.Find(1).Users.ToList();//Get all Teacher
```